# Installation error Camaleon Cms Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, camaleon

I am trying to install Camaleon CMS but getting following error:

```
undefined method `decorate' for #<CamaleonCms::Site:0x007f399a3beb58>
```

My Rails version is: 5.0.4
Ruby version is: 2.3.4

Is it the version issue, because i have read somewhere that this CMS is not compatible with higher versions of Rails like 5.0.0 and above.

I have tried to fix it but no luck!

Comment: Can you let us know, on running what command, you got this error. Also, the steps you did to install Camaleon CMS

Comment: I got this error why i hit the Next button on first screen, after filling Host, Name and selected theme

Comment: First line on their github page says it is build for Rails 4 `Camaleon CMS is a dynamic and advanced content management system based on Ruby on Rails 4.`, I think they have no support for v5+

Answer (score 3):

If this happens after you define your site name, if you define it 0.0.0.0:3000 (Which was my situation), just define the site using localhost:3000.

### EDIT

Also make sure to add this to your Gemfile in rails 5
gem 'draper', '~> 3'